# Using go with redis - not able to connect

Tags: azure, go, kubernetes, redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm trying to connect to Redis service in azure

I use the following code:

```
    import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "github.com/go-redis/redis"
    )


func main() {
     uri := os.Getenv("uri")
     fmt.Println("uri is", uri)
     opt, err := redis.ParseURL(uri)
     if err != nil {
         fmt.Println(err)
      }
     fmt.Println("addr is:”, opt.Addr)
     fmt.Println("db is:”, opt.DB)
     fmt.Println("password is:”, opt.Password)
     //connect to redis
     client = redis.NewClient(opt)
     //Here I want to get connection
     pong, err := client.Ping().Result()
```

https://github.com/go-redis/redis

https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#example-ParseURL

**The printed data is like following** I was able to the the connection string

```
uri is rediss://:bBMfQ7wFdkPHr8u%2B2zzNOzUpy85OEjYv7KbPZd8B89M%3D@e49ab3c6-8f72-416a-a6c1-ddfe75gf200e.redis.cache.windows.net:6380


addr is: e49ab3c6-8f72-416a-a6c1-ddfe75gf200e.redis.cache.windows.net:6380
db is: 0
password is: bBMfQ7wFdkPHr8u+2zzNOzUpy85OEjYv7KbPZd8B89M=
```

The Redis service is up and running and I was able to connect with `nodejs` application and **get the data**, any idea why I got the error in go:

**dial tcp 40.128.8.87:6380: connect: connection refused**

We are trying to migrate some apps from Nodejs to go ...

**The strange thing** is that in **nodejs** I use the following which works!

https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis

```
const redisClient = redis.createClient(process.env.uri);

redisClient.on("connect", () => console.log("Redis is connected"));
```

**update**

I've provisioned a new instance **without ssl** which is not working either

**This is the logs**

```
uri is redis://:TKq1n%2BO29jsSdIkoysXL%2Btwd6Xi0IO0KNxw%3D@2dca2dx1-20e0-48ca-83ed-20bf52e99b97.redis.cache.windows.net:6379
addr is 2dca2dx1-20e0-48ca-83ed-20bf52e99b97.redis.cache.windows.net:6379
db is 0
password is TKq1n+O29jsSdIkoysXL+twd6Xi0IO0KNxw=
 dial tcp 40.113.7.3:6379: connect: connection refused
```

Any idea how should I use the GO api to connect to redis properly ?

Btw, when I connected to **local** Redis it works, but not to azure cache

like this

```
client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr: "localhost:6379",
        Password: "",
        DB: 0,
    })
```

Maybe I miss something in the Redis api, as I do the same (connect to the same service instance )  for nodejs and it works!

Comment: Try running `nc e49ab3c6-8f72-416a-a6c1-ddfe75gf200e.redis.cache.windows.net 6380` to check that you server is actually accepting connection on that port and address.

Comment: @Imaxd - the service runnig on k8s specific ns, how should I check it ? I've got the kubeconfig...

Comment: Is your Go client configured to use TLS?  Port 6380 is the TLS port.in Azure.

Comment: @JonCole  Im not sure but I assume from the port number, is there a way to pass it with the go api ? with node we dont provide any tls etc and it work for the same exact instance ...

Comment: Can you try to run a shell into the container in k8s and run nc from there ?

Comment: @JonCole - please see my update, I've provisioned another instance without  ssl, and I get the same error, any idea ?

Comment: @Imaxd - I try to run the following `kubectl exec  gomaapi-649f59f744-mnt48 gomaapi -n apps bash
` and I got error: `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"gomaapi\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
` we have istio hence we have two contaniers in the pod,any idea?

Comment: try `kubectl  -n you_namespace exec -it  gomaapi-649f59f744-mnt48 exec -it sh`

Comment: @Imaxd - i've tried - `kubectl -n appstudio exec -it gomaapi-649f59f744-mnt48 exec -it sh  `   and I got the same error , any idea ?

Comment: Sorry the command is incorrect: try this `kubectl -n you_namespace exec -it gomaapi-649f59f744-mnt48 sh`

Comment: Also you might not have nc installed in the container image.

Comment: @Imaxd - thanks now I was able to exec, when I run the `nc host port ` nothing happen, its hangs , I dont get any error or any log, it's just waiting, I try to both redis services, the one with ssl and the other without ssl, any idea ?

Comment: Thanks likely means you pod does not have access to the internet.

Comment: @Imaxd   Thank you :) , One question, do you think im not using the API as I should, Do I miss something? I just want to get the `pong` signal :)   which should be rather simple but not working for me ...https://github.com/go-redis/redis

Comment: I think you code is fine: the server is not accepting connection that's it. Test you code from outside Kubernetes.

Comment: @Imaxd - Yes this is what I think before, but I was able to to connect to exact same instance with node js application and got connection ... so it may be related to the go api, what do you think?